# Overlapped Textview when text size increased + RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have tried everything but not succeed yet.

**What Happening**. When title text is small it should come in center of parent which **works perfectly**, but when text size is big its overlapped to its left sided component

**What i want** : it shouldn't not overlap but comes to next of **settings** `Textview`. it should be adjust when size increased.

**small size**
[image]

**big size**
[image]

**Code**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="16.0sp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtBack"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why are you using relative layout instead of work will relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using match_parent for those two TextViews, that is why they will being overlapped, based on your code, you can try to add a fix padding  for the second TextView. For example, we consider the width of the first TextView's text "Settings" is 100dp, so we can change the code as below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="16.0sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="100dp"            
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtBack"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks its help me but it must be single line. and string should be visible not dot dot

Comment: Understand, then I think you need to use auto scale text view, here is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/1297615

Answer (score 0):

set id to your first `TextView` and then make second `TextView` `toRightOf` first one.

**Like This**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textview1"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="16.0sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textview1"

        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtBack"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="16.0sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtSetting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtBack"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use layout_toLeftOf ,alignParentLeft and alignParentRight**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/txtBack"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selectaccount"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: what about when text is small sized.?? either small or big it should comes in center of parent

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace Your Code By Below:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="16.0sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtSettings" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtSettings"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtBack"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but it not center of parent (relativelayout). try with 4 text word

Comment: use CenterInParent="true" in center title textView

Comment: One more thing are you using txtBack ???  as In current code I am not able to see txtBack declared.. So please check it and if you are not using then let me know .

Answer (score 0):

change second textview to this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiiiii StackOverflower!!!!!!!!!!!"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstTextview"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />
```